# how to concatenate all lines in file that start with //! to make them into one line in python

Tags: python

so the file  looks like this

```
void funct_example ( int stamo)
{
    //! ID{SWERT- 12345} this is function that is suppose to take
    //! IDREF{SYA-dfjk} 
    return(stamo)
}

void funcert (string nitr)
{
    //! ID{SWERT-1324} this function is to store the string and parse it
    //! IDREF{SYA-5677} 
    return(nitr)
}
```

i want to open this file and merge all the lines start with `//!` into one line

Comment: would the result be `//! ID{SWERT-1324} this function is to store the string and parse it //! IDREF{SYA-5677} ` , all on one line?

Answer (score 0):

As your question isn't very detailed, this does exactly what you have described:

```py
import re

' '.join([line.rstrip() for line in open('/path/to/file') if re.match('^\s*//!', line)])
```

It loops through the file and filters for lines matching the regex `^\s+//!`, then it outputs a list of lines with any trailing whitespace or newline characters removed and finally joins the list with a space.

If you want the lines to be joined without the leading whitespace or `//!` then it just requires adding a regex substitution to the line output:

```py
import re

' '.join([re.sub('^\s+//!\s*', '', line.rstrip()) for line in open('/path/to/file') if re.match('^\s*//!', line)]
```